# Best option to interface laptop with blu-ray disk rewriter

Tags: usb, laptop, sata, dvd

I have a blu-ray disk rewriter ([this model](https://www.lg.com/us/burners-drives/lg-BH10LS30-internal-blu-ray-dvd-drive)), which I would like to gift to someone, who owns a laptop, but not a desktop computer, and isn't very tech-comfortable. Ideally, they would plug it into a usb port, and be able to use it. However, the rewriter only has a SATA port. With this in mind, I bought a SATA to USB3 adapter ([this one](https://www.amazon.com.au/SZJUNXIAO-SATA-USB-3-0-Adapter/dp/B0BVKM9QPT)). However, I have now come to the unfortunate realisation that the usb connection does not provide enough power for it to operate. (The rewriter has "5V/12V  1.5A/1.5A" annotated on it). Are there any cheap options for how to get it to work with a laptop usb port? Is it possible? I would rather not buy an expensive docking station.

If there is any other way to make this work, I would also be open to that. My goal is to allow a non-tech savvy person to connect to and operate the rewriter from their laptop.

Comment: there are powered versions of the adapter you bought. https://www.amazon.com.au/UNITEK-Adapter-Converter-Universal-Optical/dp/B00DHBWHA0 or https://www.amazon.com.au/Simplecom-SA491-Adapter-Power-Supply/dp/B075WZ5321 or whatever. They tend to be a bit more expensive

Comment: There are USB BlueRay drives that are cheaper than the adapter itself.

Comment: @Ramhound And that LG BH12LS30 sure ain't cheap (tho it has good specs)

Comment: @Gantendo I scavenged the rewriter from a computer I wasn't using, it didn't cost me anyhing. I was hoping for more of a discount option for an adapter.

Comment: @Ironfilings I understand; but I doubt you'll find a powered adapter that is much cheaper than 50 euro if you live in the civilized world or the USA. Probably best to get a cheap USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, the cleaner and most convenient one will be to use a SATA to USB with external power (like the Startech USB312SAT3), so you can inject the extra power needed to run the drive. This one is NOT cheap.

On the other hand USB2 standard allows only 0.5A of current per port, so even using a USB power grabber cable wont be enough, BUT USB3 gives 1A, so if your laptop has them, this cable might work. This one is cheap but the cable is hard to find sometimes and might not work at all.

The other option, a bit nasty but is way cheaper and will surely work, will be to remove the actual optical drive from the laptop, get a 13 pin Slimline SATA extension to regular 15 pin SATA, and externally connect the drive with SATA. You will have an ugly cable getting out the laptop, you might need to open the laptop to properly attach the cable, but it will cost you no more than $5 usd.

Comment: there *are* cheapush ones that inject power - I have an aliexpress one that has a 12v in, that runs a 3.5 inch drive

Comment: yeah, but I don't trust some electronics from Aliexpress or any very cheap adaptors, specially the ones dealing with drives or those which are used to move data

Comment: @ElGucs And that's *your* problem. Price has np correlation with quality/reliability

Comment: Of course it does, it's not the same to have a power delivery with no extra protection components to save 2 cents on manufacture and risk a drive of being fried because the capacitors they used are recovered ones with degraded electrolyte. There are many electronic youtubers which have proven with oscilloscopes how bad quality components or deficient designs give higher noise on their outputs and are potential risks.

Comment: @ElGucs Did they or you tested the cheap ones Journeyman Geek or me are using successfully for some years now? I don't think so. The facts are as such: The products you can find in Aliexpress come from the same factories with the same quality standard and control than the vast majority of the over-priced Amazon ones and more often than not they're the exact same products rebranded. All Startech products are exactly that.

Comment: It's good to know you guys have found good quality for those devices, but anecdotal info doesn't prove the point. 
Many generic brandless electronics have very little to no quality inspection. 
Generic electronics with brands do have some quality inspection and sometimes can be as good as known brands. Usually these generic brands use the same fabs from known brands or even refurbish rejects meant to be for known brands. 
And known brands have higher requirements and quality inspections, since they have to deal with guarantees and higher expectations with their customers.

Comment: And Yes, in electronics there is no guarantee a higher price will mean a better quality, but chances are a really cheap electronic will surely have cut corners somewhere (like not using a zener diode at the end of a regulation phase and thus having the risk of no regulation at all)
So if you are ok with using power supplies from really cheap sources and use it on your sensitive data storage, it's ok, it's you who is taking the risk, but don't say "that's your problem" because, as I've said, it has been demonstrated many times.

Comment: So you want anecdotals, fine, I've bought many electronics there too, recently I even got some nice USB testers from there with superb quality, but I've also found many terrible ones and some have fried other electronics. Even expensive brands like Sony or Apple have terrible stuff, but the common thing is: *super* cheap electronics = *very possible* to be bad ones, that's my point.